# Query regarding reactor.doSelect() and reactor.runUntilCurrent

Tags: python, twisted

I am working on a game prototype using python twisted. Referring one of the books, I am currently using the following code to update the games

```
def iterate(self):
    now = time.time()
    interval = now - self.beginFrame
    self.beginFrame = now

    # update the network
    reactor.runUntilCurrent()        
    reactor.doSelect(0)

    # update the games
    for game in self.games:
        game.update(interval)
```

However, the above code fails in ubuntu machine with error "AttributeError: 'EPollReactor' object has no attribute 'doSelect'" . I am using twisted 16.1.1 and following are my questions

1) I didn't find runUntilCurrent and doSelect methods in the documentation given in twistedmatrix, are these methods not available anymore?

2) Is reactor.iterate() replacement of doSelect() ?
3) From earlier posts I found that reactor.iterate() may make the application slow and buggy. What is the best way to handle situations where one requires fact UI updates?

Answer (score 0):

Twisted usually selects the epoll reactor by default. The [`doSelect`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.html#doSelect) function is available in the the [`selectreactor`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.selectreactor.html). To use the select reactor, first install the select reactor then import `twisted.internet.reactor`.

```
from twisted.internet import selectreactor
selectreactor.install()
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

Select should work on most relevant operating systems which may be why your book uses it.

> 1) I didn't find runUntilCurrent and doSelect methods in the documentation given in twistedmatrix

You're not looking hard enough mate :D try searching through all the [modules and class documents](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/moduleIndex.html) next time.

> 2) Is `reactor.iterate()` replacement of `doSelect()`.

They both seem to do something similar, but I don't think they're intended to be replacements. Hopefully a Twisted core developer will see this question and correct me if I'm wrong.